# Remove an event from jQuery queue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I want to remove the CalculateCost event when it meets a certain criteria. There isn't any room for design changes, this is what I have to work with: layout, is an aspx page with a jquery tab (each tab is a .net user control). The tabs are added dynamically. Within this user control the follow input element exist and the method bound to the onchange event is the target.

```
<input type="text" id="txtCost" disabled="disabled" onkeypress="return isValidMoney(event);" onchange="CalculateCost(true, false); ValidateCostPerUOM(this);" runat="server"/>
```

What is happening: when this field is being edited and doesn't lose focus the event is not fired. The user doesn't trigger the blur and selects a different tab. the onchange event is fired by (jQuery or .net) but during the function execution the selected tab value changes hosing things up.

What I'd like to do in the jQuery tab's select method is check for this method in the execution queue and remove (or stop it). I have no code samples because I have no clue where to start. I tried looking at the jQuery.queue() api doc but was fruitless.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What does this have to do with a queue?

Comment: Kevin. Idk lol that's why I'm asking. How do I intercept the textbox's onchange event when it's not triggered by the user?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to other than overriding it completely.

Comment: Oh! Damn it. Thanks, I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: The main reason is there can be only one event stored in the attribute, and it gets executed first. So overriding it with your own event that also does what the old one did would be the only way